# Sierpinski carpet in processing

Tags: processing, fractals

So I made the Sierpinski carpet fractal in processing using a `Square` data type which draw a square and has a function `generate()` that generates 9 equal squares out of itself and returns an `ArrayList` of **(9-1)=8** squares removing the middle one (it is not added to the returned `ArrayList`) in order to generate the Sierpinski carpet.

### Here is the class Square -

```java
class Square {

  PVector pos;
  float r;

  Square(float x, float y, float r) {
    pos = new PVector(x, y);
    this.r = r;
  }
  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(120,80,220);
    rect(pos.x, pos.y, r, r);
  }
  ArrayList<Square> generate() {

    ArrayList<Square> rects = new ArrayList<Square>();

    float newR = r/3;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        if (!(i==1 && j==1)) {
          Square sq = new Square(pos.x+i*newR, pos.y+j*newR, newR);
          rects.add(sq);
        }
      }
    }

    return rects;
  }
}
```

This is the main sketch which moves forward the generation on mouse click -

```java
ArrayList<Square> current;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  current = new ArrayList<Square>();

  current.add(new Square(0, 0, width));
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (Square sq : current) {
    sq.display();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  ArrayList<Square> next = new ArrayList<Square>();

  for(Square sq: current) {
    ArrayList<Square> rects = sq.generate();
    next.addAll(rects);
  }
  current = next;
}
```

### The problem :

The output that I am getting has very thin white lines which are not supposed to be there :

## First generation - [image]

## Second generation - [image]

## Third generation - [image]

My guess is that these lines are just the white background that shows up due to the calculations in `generate()` being off by a pixel or two. However I am not sure about how to get rid of these. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I notice that you're calling `noStroke()` when you display square. I don't use processing but I've seen similar problems in other contexts where I needed to both stroke and fill the square.

Comment: You said that you have a guess about what's happening. That means it's time to [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program to try to confirm your suspicions. Try to narrow it down to just a single square. What are its coordinates and size? How are they being drawn? If you still can't get it figured out after narrowing it down to a single square, then please post a [mcve] showing just that square instead of your whole sketch, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I confirmed my suspicion and its exactly what's happening! Right now, the canvas is 600x600 which is divisible wholly by 3 only once, if we divide again we go into decimals and white lines appear on generation 2.

Now, I change the size to 900x900 which is divisible wholly by 3 two times, hence this time the white lines appear after 2 generations, i.e, on the third generation! However, I can't figure out how to fix this exactly.

Comment: @KevinWorkman One quick fix is to remove `noStroke()` and make the stroke the same colour as the fill, it removes the lines but messes up the smaller squares in later generations and makes them look out of position which is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a smaller example that demonstrates your problem:

```
size(1000, 100);
noStroke();
background(0);

float squareWidth = 9.9;
for(float squareX = 0; squareX < width; squareX += squareWidth){
 rect(squareX, 0, squareWidth, height); 
}
```

[image: squares with artifact]

Notice that the black background is showing through the squares. Please try to post this kind of minimal example instead of your whole sketch in the future.

Anyway, there are three ways to fix this:

**Option 1:** Call the `noSmooth()` function.

By default, Processing uses anti-aliasing to make your drawings look smoother. Usually this is a good thing, but it can also add some fuzziness to the edges of shapes. If you disable anti-aliasing, your shapes will be more clear and you won't see the artifacts.

**Option 2:** Use a stroke with the same color as the fill.

As you've already discovered, this draws an outline around the shape.

**Option 3:** Use `int` values instead of `float` values.

You're storing your coordinates and sizes in `float` values, which can contain decimal places. The problem is, the screen (the actual pixels on your monitor) don't have decimal places (there is no such thing as half a pixel), so they're represented by `int` values. So when you convert a `float` value to an `int`, the decimal part is dropped, which can cause small gaps in your shapes.

If you just switch to using `int` values, the problem goes away:

```
size(1000, 100);
noStroke();
background(0);

int squareWidth = 10;
for(int squareX = 0; squareX < width; squareX += squareWidth){
 rect(squareX, 0, squareWidth, height); 
}
```

Comment: Option 1, just like option 2, makes the white line disappear but distorts the smaller square, and option 3 still leaves white lines, but differently in the final image. [Here are some pictures for each case.](http://imgur.com/a/rUJHr)

Comment: @MasterYushi The `int` conversion has to happen from the beginning. You can't convert from `float` to `int`. you have to store everything as an `int`.

Comment: I did exactly that, rewrote the whole class with `int`

Comment: @MasterYushi `PVector` uses `float` internally.